# Copy/clone an entire WPF solution& project and use it under another name

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a **WPF** *solution & project*(written in Visual Studio2019) that I would like to use under another name.

On the other words, I have a project like( *EXAMPLE_A* ) that I would like to use on my other task (not creating again the entire project) just copy & paste and rename it (*EXAMPLE_B*) and then I want to exchange the GUI colors and title and logos...

I tried this copy&paste way but some part of code was wrong: VS said some part of code are not included in this project and so on . However, I copied the entire folder. I saw the Save As is not option... Therefore, I ask your help what is the correct process.

**The question:** have a simple correct way to clone/ copy the solution and use it under another separated name? ( final outcome: have EXAMPLE_A and EXAMPLE_B separately with same program functions, different name and logo)

Thank you for you all support.

Comment: "want to exchange the GUI colors and title and logos" - that doesn't require copying project source code. (imaging copying .net libs every time you want to change some text Foreground)

Comment: Just search for the old name over all files and replace it with the new. There are references to class names not only in the file names, but also in the code itself, in xaml files, resource files etc.

Comment: Thanks @ASh. I tried to meaning: in the past I have created an WPF application for a business task. And now I would like to clone that application (to keep A and B) for the new and same project. But is it important to use and store it in different name. And I have to use this copied version under another name (with the same functions). And maybe in the future I have to add something only for projectA or only in  projectB, based on the business requests.  Sorry if I was wrong/ not clear. Thanks once more.

Comment: @PMF In my Example.xaml.cs there is a Properties.Settings.Default.Reload(); that VS underlines and said Properties does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score -1):

Export your project as a [Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022) in Visual Studio, then you can create another project and change the name or whatever else you need.